# Deleting Multiple Keys in Redis

Tags: redis, xargs

In my redis database, I'm trying to delete a series of keys that start with:

`EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_`

I have tried the following:

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p myport -a mypassword --scan --pattern EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_* | xargs redis-cli unlink
```

and

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p myport -a mypassword --scan --pattern EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_* | xargs redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p myport -a mypassword unlink
```

But, I get the following error message:

```
'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Could anyone help as to why xargs won't work in this case? I see that same syntax above being mentioned quite a few times here and seems to work for others...

EDIT: I forgot to mention that when I run the first half of the line before the pipe, it does return all the keys that match the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the work; (added an example print-out)

> redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a mypass --scan --pattern EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_* | xargs redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a mypass unlink

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config set requirepass mypass
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> auth mypass
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_a a
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_b a
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_c a
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> set EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_d a
OK
127.0.0.1:6379>

redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a mypass --scan --pattern EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_* | xargs redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a mypass unlink
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
Warning: Using a password with '-a' or '-u' option on the command line interface may not be safe.
(integer) 4


127.0.0.1:6379> auth mypass
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> exists EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_a
(integer) 0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've tried that and get exactly the same:
```'xargs' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.```

Comment: @BaroN do you use windows ?

Comment: Yes. Windows server 2012 r2

Comment: @BaroN xargs is not available on windows - that's the reason you are getting error i think. You may need to install some tools to use `xargs` such as https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki

Comment: Thanks, this got me a bit further but now I get the error message ```(error) ERR unknown command 'unlink'```

Comment: @BaroN please replace `unlink` with `del`

Comment: thanks again. Tried that and now I get this error message: ```(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'del' command```

Comment: @BaroN please be sure that at least one matching key exists in your database. then it wouldn't give an error.

Comment: There are lots of matching keys...maybe too many? If I run the query up to the pipe, it returns 3,003 rows of keys

Comment: Did you see my note about matching keys? So, there are matching keys but, unlink or del won't work still. Any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: @BaroN i just saw and tried and it is working on my env. The number of keys don't matter in this case and 3003 is fine. After the pipe `xargs redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 -a mypass del` worked on me.

Comment: thanks for all your help. I don't know why it's simply just not working for me. Really strange

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is a common Linux utility and the message you are seeing indicates you are using Windows. You have a couple of choices here to get this working - you can find a Windows alternative of `xargs`, use Cygwin, use Powershell, etc.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I tried running powershell out of the redis folder and I get this error:
```redis-cli : The term 'redis-cli' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6381 -a mypass --scan --pattern EPOCH_vgsOwnedVehs_*
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (redis-cli:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Powershell requires similar notation as Linux shells - so if you want to run something from current folder you need to prefix it with .\ , e.g. .\redis-cli

Comment: Thanks, this also got me a bit further but, same problem as above, I get the following error message ```(error) ERR unknown command 'unlink'```